# Yawning sounds from the phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, audio

For the past month my Samsung Galaxy S3 has been making yawning noises. No im not crazy, I have witnesses. Why is it doing that and how can I stop it?

Comment: Do you have skype installed by any chance ? Also if it is not too much trouble upload the clip on soundcloud and link it !

Comment: Maybe it's just tired. Have you tried not using it for a while? Let it sleep a little!

Answer (score 2):

There could be two reasons for this, I am assuming I know what sound you are talking about since you have not provided an audio example.

- You have sounds for phone sleep and phone awake in your settings
  and/or you have notification sounds enabled.
- You have skype installed with the notifications on for people
  login/logout, the logout makes a yawning sound.

Check this out and I guess one of them is your root cause :)